# Datetime conversion of a financial Period

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a financial period in the system as '201801' how do I convert it to (01/04/2018) where (2018) is year and (01) is financial period but April not Jan

```
 so example
 201801 - 01/04/2018
 201802 - 01/05/2018
 201803 - 01/06/2018
 201803 - 01/07/2018
 201803 - 01/08/2018
 201803 - 01/09/2018
 201803 - 01/10/2018
 201803 - 01/11/2018
 201803 - 01/12/2018
 201803 - 01/01/2019
 201803 - 01/02/2019
 201803 - 01/03/2019
```

I am using MSSQL and SSMS

Comment: well where are you getting the months from? i.e. 1-12. Are we to assume there is only 12 rows for any given year / period? How are the periods seperated? Why is 03 duplicated so many times?

Comment: the data doesn't seem consistent. 03 spans many months

Comment: In your question, is `01/04/2018` April 1st, or January 4th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 3 months:

```
select dateadd(month, 3, datefromparts(left(period, 4), right(period, 2), 1)) as period_start
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for :) You are a Legend

Comment: @RegChand . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Yes because removing 0 from formula gives me date exactly as per period converted to date and adding 3 gives me financial period ie. starting from April. Also  I cant have a static period specified using @a so this works perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code:

```
DECLARE @a INT
SET @a = '201802'
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 3, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(@a,'01')))
```

**Output obtained for 201802:**

```
2018-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

PS: This will only work when the difference of span is 3 months. (Jan-April)